# Filters and Accelerometers

Tags: filter, accelerometer

I have just started working with the accelerometers and have referred few docs related to same.
So I came across the filters used in accelerometers. I need to know, Why are there filters in the accelerometers? Are they always required? How does it effect the digital data that has been received from the accelerometer?

Regards.

Comment: You might want to target a specific device and show some insight into the type of filter used to avoid a series of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Study this: -

[image]

Acceleration (as a signal) can be converted to velocity by integration. Velocity can be converted to positional change by integration.

So, if you have an accelerometer and you want to know how far an object has moved, attach the accelerometer to the object and double integrate the output to get distance moved.

An integrator is a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering is needed to remove noise from sampled data. Usualy you would use a low pass FIR filter with 2^N taps that will induce a delay that is (2^N)/2 time samples.